# Convert Hex string to Binary string C#

Tags: c#, string, binary, hex

I am trying to convert hex string into binary. My code looks as follows:

```
sw.Write(Convert.ToString(Convert.ToInt32(value, 16), 2));
```

However this works for most of the values; But when I convert hex string 0x101 to binarystring, my result is 100000001, rathen than 000100000001. Please help me.

Comment: Well that *is* the binary value. Are you saying you need to always pad to a multiple of 4 digits?

Comment: Does it matter? The leading 0 are not significant...

Comment: Yes it does matter in my application. So if I have Hex = 001, then Binary should become 000000000001. How do I do this?

Comment: `if I have Hex = 001`. Is `Hex` an integer or string?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

How about using String.PadLeft() ?

```
string value = "0x001";
string binary = Convert.ToString(Convert.ToInt32(value, 16), 2).PadLeft(12, '0');
```

Comment: You can't just hardcode 12 like that; what if the hex value is 0x1001 ? Then you need to pad to 16 characters..

Comment: @ThomasLevesque the 12 in PadLeft() is the total length of the string after padding. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/92h5dc07(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Yes, I know what PadLeft does... but it will only work for numbers that are less then 12 binary digits. The OP needs to pad to a multiple of 4 digits. If value is 0x1001, the non-padded result will have 13 digits, and padding it to 12 digits will have no effect; you need to pad it to 16 in that case.

Answer (score 5):

```
string Hex = "001";
var s = String.Join("", 
          Hex.Select(x => Convert.ToString(Convert.ToInt32(x+"", 16), 2).PadLeft(4,'0')));
```

Comment: How do I do the reverse Binary to Hex? Binary string 000001010100
 should become 054?

Comment: @savi Why do you ask me?